# Robot Framework: IF/ELSE - Using keyword within another keyword

Tags: robotframework

I am a complete beginner when it comes to robot framework, my apologies if this is a silly question.

So I have a user defined keyword here:

```
GET call to an API
      [Arguments]  ${user_uuid}  ${country_uuid}  ${http_status_code}
      ${json_date_uuid} =  Set Variable  $.date
     #code here#  
    
      ${response} =  Trigger GET  ${HTTP_SERVER}  ${APP_UUID}  ${PRI_KEY}  ${get_endpoint}  ${secs_headers}  ${no_query_param}
      Log  Endpoint GET Result:
      Log  ${response.status_code}
      Log  ${response.content}
```

Now I am trying to do a validation to check the `response.status_code` to see if it is returning 200 or 404.

If it is 200, I want it to run the following steps:

```
Should Be Equal As Strings  ${response.status_code}  ${status_code}
${milestone_definition} =  Retrieve Json Value  ${response.content}  ${json_date_uuid}
List Should Contain Value  ${value}  12345
```

If it is 404, I want it to run the following:

```
Should Be Equal As Strings  ${response.status_code}  ${status_code}
```

So I have tried the following where I defined the steps as keywords under the **GET call to an API** keyword and call them using IF/ELSE IF but to no avail:

```
GET call to an API
   [Arguments]  ${user_uuid}  ${country_uuid}  ${http_status_code}
   ${json_date_uuid} =  Set Variable  $.date
   #code here#
                
   ${response} =  Trigger GET  ${HTTP_SERVER}  ${APP_UUID}  ${PRI_KEY}  ${get_endpoint}  
   ${secs_headers}  ${no_query_param}
   Log  Endpoint GET Result:
   Log  ${response.status_code}
   Log  ${response.content}
            
   Run Keyword If  ${response.status_code} == 200  GET SEC Success Validation  ELSE IF ${response.status_code} == 404  GET SEC Failure Validation
                    
#Validation
GET SEC Success Validation
   Should Be Equal As Strings  ${response.status_code}  ${status_code}
   ${milestone_definition} =  Retrieve Json Value  ${response.content}  ${json_date_uuid}
   List Should Contain Value  ${value}  12345
                
GET SEC Failure Validation GET
   Should Be Equal As Strings  ${response.status_code}  ${status_code}
```

Unfortunately it returns the following error when I run the command:

> Keyword 'API_Keywords.GET SEC Success Validation' expected 0
> arguments, got 2.

Any tips or guidances on how I can achieve this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake

```
Run Keyword If  ${response.status_code} == 200  GET SEC Success Validation  ELSE IF 
${response.status_code} == 404  GET SEC Failure Validation
```

This schould do what you want. (in one line with double space between "IF" and "${response.status_code}"-sry double spaces pass it into a new line)

Sometimes there are Problems with the ELSE/IF Funktion so alternative you can use:

```
Run Keyword If  ${response.status_code} == 200  GET SEC Success Validation
Run Keyword If  ${response.status_code} == 404  GET SEC Failure Validation
```

This should guarantee to run your code proper
For more Information check the BuiltIn Librarie

If you need to pass variables from one Keyword to another there are two ways:

1. Use global Variables (not recommended )

   `Suite Setup  Set Suite/Global/Local Variable  name  value`
2. Pass the needed Variables as Arguments

```
Run Keyword If  ${response.status_code} == 200  GET SEC Success Validation  ${arg1.1}  ${arg1.2}

GET SEC Success Validation
  [Arguments]  ${arg1.1}  ${arg1.2}
```

```
Run Keyword If  ${response.status_code} == 404  GET SEC Failure Validation  ${arg2.1}  ${arg2.2}

GET SEC Failure Validation GET
  [Arguments]  ${arg2.1}  ${arg2.2}
```

I hope u understand this. Write a Command if u have more questions or i missunderstood something

Comment: Thank you! Though passing the variables as arguments didn't work (maybe I did something wrongly, but using Set Test Variable did the job.

Comment: Glad to hear i could help you. If you want we can find out why passing Arguments did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple `if, else if, else` structure using the [Run Keyword If](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20If). The documentation of the keyword even has an example for such use-case.

> ```
> ${var1}=  Run Keyword If  ${rc} == 0  Some keyword returning a value      
> ...   ELSE IF     0 < ${rc} < 42  Another keyword         
> ...   ELSE IF     ${rc} < 0   Another keyword with args   ${rc}   arg2
> ...   ELSE    Final keyword to handle abnormal cases  ${rc}
> ```

Starting from Robot Framework 4.0 the new [`IF/ELSE IF/ELSE`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#if-expression) syntax can be used.

```
IF    ${rc} == 0
    ${var1}=    Some keyword returning a value
ELSE IF    0 < ${rc} < 42
    ${var1}=    Another keyword
ELSE IF    ${rc} < 0
    ${var1}=    Another keyword with args   ${rc}   arg2
ELSE
    ${var1}=    Final keyword to handle abnormal cases  ${rc}
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Without checking the documentation (I suspect that there is no ELSE IF), here is my proposal:

```
Run Keyword If  ${response.status_code} == 200  GET SEC Success Validation  ELSE  Run Keyword If  ${response.status_code} == 404  GET SEC Failure Validation
```

or

```
Run Keyword If  ${response.status_code} == 200  GET SEC Success Validation
Run Keyword If  ${response.status_code} == 404  GET SEC Failure Validation
```

or

```
Run Keyword If  ${response.status_code} == 200  GET SEC Success Validation
Run Keyword Unless  ${response.status_code} == 200  Run Keyword If  ${response.status_code} == 404  GET SEC Failure Validation
```

Comment: Thank you! I think the 2nd option you've suggested worked but I'm still getting so much error to know properly (at least the error message is different now). Perhaps I was also unclear in my initial question, but aside from the if/else statement, I also wanted to understand how I could get the variables from 'GET call to an API' keyword and use them in 'GET SEC Success Validation' and 'GET SEC Success Validation' keyword as well.